# Is there a way to mark inline code without backticks in comments?

Tags: support, mobile-web, android, backtick

When on my Android device the keyboard does not have backticks (or I don't know how to access them... - I am on a german layout btw), therefore I am unable to add `code` parts in comments et. al.

Is there another way to mark inline code? I do think it improves readability a whole lot so it should be done wherever possible.

Comment: there should always be a way to enter those characters... usually there is more than one page of symbols... some times a long press will also display additional symbols.

Comment: @Lix, yes there are two pages with special characters, yet no backtick. Also, I have searched every (no kidding) sub-menu of the standard letters. Still no backtick.

Comment: I have a Galaxy S running ICS and I checked out the german layouts - I can see the backtick character on the second page of symbols... For me its the page with the square `[]` and curly `{}` braces...

Comment: @Lix I'm on HTC Sense and they have a different keyboard (XT9) than Samsung unfortunately. No backticks for me.... But thanks a lot for looking!

Comment: May I suggest using [slideIT](http://www.mobiletextinput.com/Product/What_is_SlideIT/)?  Or installing any other alternative keyboard - they can sometimes be much better than the stock keyboards...

Comment: @Lix you may :) Thanks for pointing me to this very simple, yet very fitting solution!

Comment: Heh, I considered asking this question a few days ago... my HTC Desire doesn't have the `\`` either.

Comment: I would recommend [Hacker's Keyboard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.pocketworkstation.pckeyboard), which gives you the standard 5 row keyboard including the top numbers row including the backtick key

Comment: Incidentally, an alternate keyboard program provided my with a backtick, as well, though I actually installed it for another issue.

Comment: @YiJ - I use this one always when I'm in an SSH session - its got EVERYTHING! :P

Comment: Wow, seriously? A keyboard without a backtick? Even the iPhone has a backtick, and it doesn't even have a real keyboard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the "new comment" text box is plain without any editor attached so no other way to mark inline code in a comment.

My 2 cents:

1. You can mark it *italic* or **bold** using the `*` character to distinguish it from rest of the comment.
2. You can post the text in the New Answer editor, mark the part you want to be code and click the Code Sample icon ([image]) of the editor - backticks will be automagically added to the selected text. Then copy this back to the comment textbox and post it.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**: Sorry I misread the question. OP is referring to comments, and not posts. `<code>` will only work on Posts.

---

I believe as well as using backticks you can also use:

`<code>code here..</code>`

As shown in the [markdown syntax page](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#precode)

Therefore your android device should allow you to use inline code.

Comment: +1 - however it *is* terribly verbose :)

Comment: <code>alert('This is a test')</code>

Comment: @m90 :P But yea - not in the comments :P  Install a new keyboard already!

Comment: Doesn't seem to work unfortunately.... I'm with my brand new keyboard btw right now so `Yay for that`

Comment: @m90 Sorry I didn't realise your question was just referring to comments.